# Converter um objeto do tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List no tipo 'System.Data.DataSet'?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List no tipo 'System.Data.DataSet'?

Após fazer uma consulta de um relatório, estou guardando os dados em uma lista e mostrando os dados na tela, mais eu tenho uma opção de exportação dos dados para o ***Excel***, então para não repetir a consulta estou guardando os dados em uma sessão.

> `Session`:

```
repeater_teste.DataSource = retorno;
Session["Ultimo_Relatorio"] = retorno
```

Na opção de exportação estou fazendo desta forma (gerando **erro**):

```
 DataSet ds = (DataSet)Session["Ultimo_Relatorio"];
 DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
 dg.AllowPaging = false;
 dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
 dg.DataBind();
```

Eu encontrei este [artigo que fala que era possível](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=pt-BR&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.com.br&sl=en&sp=nmt4&u=https://www.codeproject.com/questions/257001/store-data-set-in-session&usg=ALkJrhg4z4IbU3ykJbxYnCsso_cdVT5oyA).

Comment: Dúvida: por que não simplesmente setar a lista como binding de um DataSet?

Comment: @jbueno, me mostre como, posta um exemplo por favor

Comment: Tá, lá. Bom proveito!

Comment: O artigo fala sobre armazenar o DS na session e não de cast de List para Dataset. Pela mensagem de erro parece que o problema é do cast. Complementa a pergunta com a parte do código que vc armazena o DS na session.

Comment: @Pagotti, pergunta ajustada. mais completa

Answer (score 4):

#### Dica

Eu, sinceramente, não vejo um bom motivo para fazer isso. Isto é, é possível simplesmente fazer com que uma lista seja o *binding* de um **`DataGridView`**, então por que se dar o trabalho de fazer toda essa conversão?

Ex.:

```
dg.DataSource = minhaLista;
```

#### Resposta

De qualquer forma, aqui vai um código que faz exatamente o que você precisa

```
public static DataSet ToDataSet<T>(this IList<T> list)
{
    Type elementType = typeof(T);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    ds.Tables.Add(t);

    // Adicionar uma coluna para propriedade pública em T
    foreach (var propInfo in elementType.GetProperties())
    {
        Type ColType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propInfo.PropertyType) ?? propInfo.PropertyType;

        t.Columns.Add(propInfo.Name, ColType);
    }

    foreach (T item in list)
    {
        DataRow row = t.NewRow();

        foreach (var propInfo in elementType.GetProperties())
        {
            row[propInfo.Name] = propInfo.GetValue(item, null) ?? DBNull.Value;
        }

        t.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return ds;
}
```

Comment: eu não conseguir usar o "DataSource" pede uma referência mais ela já existe  "using System.Data;"

Comment: @itasouza Jovem, eu dei uma confundida nos nomes. Veja a edição.

Comment: então. está resposta eu já tinha "dg.DataSource = minhaLista;" só que eu preciso fazer uma nova consulta apenas para exporta para o excel, eu queria usar o que já estava na memoria

Comment: Tudo bem, mas a minha resposta tem exatamente o que você pede no final. O início é apenas uma dica.

Comment: Mais eu vou ter que fazer uma nova consulta para ter "dg.DataSource = minhaLista;" ? ou dar para deixar uma variável publica ?

Comment: Não entendi o que você quis dizer @itasouza

Comment: Tenho uma consulta de dados que já me traz o retorno dos dados mostrado na tela para o usuário, estou guardando o retorno da consulta dos dados em uma Session, porque se o usuário clicar em exporta para excel, eu vou precisar fazer uma nova consulta dos dados, então no seu exemplo eu tenho que fazer novamente a consulta porque não vou conseguir usar o conteúdo que está na memoria. @jbueno